# Django User Create Form dropdowns not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-models, drop-down-menu, django-forms

I have a user class that is subclassed from abstract user:

`models.py`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    birth_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=birth_year_choices)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_choices)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=education_choices)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=occupation_choices)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sector_choices)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['birth_year', 'gender', 'education', 'occupation', 'sector']
```

And a signup form to create such a user:
`forms.py`:

```
from .models import CustomUser

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    birth_year = forms.IntegerField()
    gender = forms.CharField()
    education = forms.CharField()
    occupation = forms.CharField()
    sector = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'birth_year', 'gender', 'education', 'occupation', 'sector','email')
```

And a class based view to display this:
`views.py`:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

My understanding is that django should automatically provide a widget.Select for each model field that has choices, and render the form with dropdowns, but it doesn't, there is just a text box. Clearly one solution is to duplicate the choices in forms.py as well as models.py, but this seems to violate django's DRY principle. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think you should remove all fields from `SignUpForm`, you are overriding the default django fields now not specifying widgets.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Comment: @PawełKordowski Perfect, do you want to put that as an answer, and I'll accept it? Thanks!

Comment: no, thanks, I'm happy your problem is solved